# Problem with tcblisting at page break

Tags: listings, page-breaking, tcolorbox

I use a tcolorbox to display my listings and thats actually works pretty well. But if in my listing a page break occurs, then my predefined "basicstyle" property will be removed. And I have no idea why. Maybe someone has an idea?

This is my code:

```
\begin{tcblisting}{
skin=enhanced,
colback=CSbackground,
boxrule=0pt,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
top=-14.8pt,
bottom=-14.8pt,
colframe=red,
listing only,
left=-2.5pt,
right=-8pt,
overlay={\fill[CSnumberbg] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0pt]frame.north west);
                \fill[CSnumberline] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-9pt]frame.north west);},
listing style=CSharp,
breakable,
bottomsep at break=14.8pt,
topsep at break=14.8pt
}
string s = "this is a string"
%many repetitions
string s = "this is a string"
\end{tcblisting}
```

And the Result:
[image]
Here is a Pagebreak.
[image]

**Update:**

The reply from Thomas was the solution. Thank you for that.
Nevertheless, here's a more complete example, with the fix from Thomas. If someone is interested.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{CSbackground}{RGB}{30, 30, 30}
\definecolor{CSkeywords}{RGB}{86, 156, 214}
\definecolor{CSstrings}{RGB}{214, 157, 133}
\definecolor{CScomments}{RGB}{96, 139, 78}
\definecolor{CSemph}{RGB}{78, 201, 176}
\definecolor{CSnumberbg}{RGB}{241, 241, 241}
\definecolor{CSnumberline}{RGB}{38, 169, 202}

\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{CSbackground},
    language=[Sharp]C,
    frame=l,
    framesep=5pt,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{White},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{CSkeywords}\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{CSstrings},
    commentstyle=\color{CScomments},
    rulecolor=\color{CSbackground},
    emph={GZipStream,StreamWriter,WebClient,additionalClasses},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{CSemph},
    xleftmargin=5pt,
    xrightmargin=5pt,
    aboveskip=\bigskipamount,
    belowskip=\bigskipamount,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1.1em,
    stepnumber=1,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{Gray}
}


\begin{tcblisting}{
    skin=enhanced,
    colback=CSbackground,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    top=-14.8pt,
    bottom=-14.8pt,
    colframe=red,
    listing only,
    left=-2.5pt,
    right=-8pt,
    overlay={\fill[CSnumberbg] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0pt]frame.north west);
                    \fill[CSnumberline] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-9pt]frame.north west);},
    listing style=CSharp,
    breakable,
    bottomsep at break=14.8pt,
    topsep at break=14.8pt,
    colupper=white
    }
    string s = "this is a string"
    %many repetitions
    string s = "this is a string"
\end{tcblisting}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the given code is not compilable and especially the information about the used `CSharp` style is missing, I cannot test the problem. But, I have a guess about the cause of the problem and so I try to give a *best guess* answer.

When a `tcolorbox` encounters a page break, the colors of the following box part are restored to their set-up values. The reason for this behavior is that (La)TeX cannot keep track of the color information during a `\vsplit` which works under the hood.

The default text color is black. I guess that your `CSharp` style sets the current text color to white which is replaced by the default black color after the break. The solution for that is to change the default text color of the `tcolorbox`. Try to add the following to your options list:

```
%...
colupper=white,
%...
```

My *guess* is that this does the trick.

Comment: If `lualatex` and `\usepackage{luacolor}` is used, even the colors should be maintained in a page break, but, as you wrote, as long the example is not compilable, it's only a guess.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not a `luatex` user, but as far as I know this is partly true. If the color is bound to a font, I think, `luatex` keeps the color in a page break, but `\color{..}` settings are lost (?). But, anyway, this is a `luatex` specific feature. :-)

Comment: Thanks alot, your guess was right! That do the trick and excuse my late reply. Spam filter has caught the mails from stackexchange.
For a better understanding: Overrides the tcolorbox, only the foreground color after a page break or even other things in the listing?

Comment: Please ignore the second part of my comment. I think I have understand it. Thank you again.